# Error when executing method of element of object array in for/in statement. p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm native Korean, so I'm sorry for my **poor English.**

I made p5.js snake-game, but 'Food' object is not working.
I debugged my code, so I wrote only the part where the problem occurred in the code.

```
var foodArray;
var scl = 20;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(300, 300);
 
  foodArray = [];
  
  foodArray.push(new Food());
  foodArray.push(new Food());
  foodArray.push(new Food());
  
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for(var food in foodArray){
    food.show(); // <- ERROR!!
    alert("for executing"); // <- NOT Executed
  }

  foodArray[1].show(); // <- this line executed well.
}

function Food() {
  this.location = createVector(parseInt(random(30)), parseInt(random(30)));

  this.show = function(){
    fill(242,242,242);
    rect(this.location.x*scl, this.location.y*scl, scl, scl);
  }
}
```

I want to know how to use for/in statement in p5.js, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `for...of` instead of `for...in`. The difference is that `for...in` iterates over the keys (indices) of the list, and `for...of` iterates over the values.

For example, consider the following code:

```
function setup() {
  let lis = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  print("for...in");
  for (let k in lis) {
    print(k);
  }
  print("for...of");
  for (let k of lis) {
    print(k);
  }
}
```

The `for...in` version prints the indices of the list, while the `for...of` version prints the values (letters). So when the computer sees `food.show()`, the variable `food` is just a number. Since there is no method `.show()` for numbers, you get an error.

Comment: Thank you very much! p5.js does not support ES6(for...of statement included), so I need to setup the p5.js-es6-boilerplate(https://github.com/woudsma/p5js-es6-boilerplate#installation). Thank you!!